# Nginx - error_log for dynamic vhosts

Tags: nginx, vhosts, error-log

How can I have an error log file for dynamic virtual hosts?

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name ~^(?<folder>[^.]*).(?<user>[^.]*).dev.example.com;

    root /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/htdocs;
    access_log /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/access.log;
    error_log  /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/error.log;
}
```

The root and access_log are working correctly but if I add the error_log line then nginx fails to start because /var/www/projects/dev/$user/$folder/ doesn't exists.

Comment: I know it's not the answer you were hoping for, but as it does answer the question, would you be so kind to accept the answer and/or award the bounty?  If you perform no action within the next 4 hours of the grace period, at least half of the bounty amount will be irrevocably lost.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty!  +1!

Answer (score 6):

This is simply not supported — you can use the variables within http://nginx.org/r/access_log, but not within http://nginx.org/r/error_log.

P.S. Note that in general, it's a pretty bad idea to use user-input variables within either `access_log` or `error_log`, since you introduce the potential for a malicious user to exhaust the [inodes on your filesystem](http://mdoc.su/o/fs.5#Inodes) by making requests with random strings in the `Host` header, which may result in creation of a new file for every new request.  This could even happen inadvertently (without a malicious intent) by someone simply trying to enumerate all the possible users on your server.  Your specific code doesn't necessarily suffer from this, as directories are not normally created automatically by any UNIX software, but it's still not the best way to do things.

In nginx philosophy, it'd be a better idea to generate a separate http://nginx.org/r/server config for each user (since nginx can be restarted without any downtime).  Consider that it has additional benefits because nginx heavily relies on mathematically efficient datastructures for finding the correct `server` (which regexp-based server configurations aren't).  Not using variables within `access_log` would also ensure that writes to the `access_log` could be buffered, which can greatly increase the effective throughput of your server (especially if you log onto non-SSD HDDs).

Basically, there are already many bandaids in nginx to support variables within `access_log` (just look at the list of limitations at http://nginx.org/r/access_log for when variables are used to specify the file), and, I guess, it was deemed inappropriate to introduce even more of such bandaids to `error_log` as well (especially given that the `error_log` in production scenarios is not supposed to be nearly as large as `access_log`, so, if necessary, you can easily write external tools to split it out).

Comment: BTW, one thing I even forgot to mention explicitly — where would you expect for the error messages to go if your `error_log` specifies a file in a directory that doesn't exist?!  It's for this and many other reasons that variables aren't (and should not be) supported for `error_log`.